# http get in android async task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-networking

When i implement this it says "NetworkOnMainThreadException".

Could someone post an example which works?

I have tried many different examples and libraries, but it didnt work. my code:

```
private class HttpGetter extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(String.valueOf(urls[0]));

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                Log.v("Getter", "Your data: " + builder.toString()); //response data
            } else {
                Log.e("Getter", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: are you sure this is your only code where you are executing http tasks? could you show the logcat?

Comment: Show how you are calling it and explain *how* it isn't working. Are you still getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` or something else is happening? Also, is this all of the task code? Do you override any of the other methods of `AsyncTask`?

Comment: You should be executing networking where you shouldn't in another place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute the task like this `new HttpGetter().execute(URL)`

Note that `AsyncTask` can be executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

how are you calling this class object. 
if you calling like this then you should not get that exception.

```
new HttpGetter().excute(new URL("http://www.urlstring.com"));
```

Alternatively you can run your code with below code without exception but **NOT RECOMMENDED**

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

ADD this permission in android manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```